# How enable Tls 1.1 and 1.2 in react native (android)

Tags: java, android, react-native, fetch, tls1.2

Well, I'm developing an app for android and IOS platform, inside my app I'm fecthing data from an API. I realised that my app can't fetch data in some android versions. I tested in andoroid 4.1, 4.4 and 5.1. These versions do not fecth data. But Android 7, fetch and I do not have problems.

I was looking for the solution, I found that androids versions using minSdkVersion 16, they do not have TLS 1.1 and 1.2 enable by default. (This is implemented from 20 sdkVersion) And to enable them, I will have to do with Java. I'm just working with react-native 3 months ago and I'm not a java programmer. So the stuffs i'm seeing around, do not tell me exactly what I'll have to do. Can any one tell me steps to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 2.2 in a react-native android app. I just see exemples that give the code to add, they do not explain or tell the steps. And I also read a comment that says by enabling the TLS 1.1 and 1.2 the app can't be uploaded in play store.

Comment: React-native allows you to write native components. Just grab some java code that works with tls 1.2 and create the RN component with it.

Comment: Can show any exemple?

Answer (score 4):

add this library in android `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:+'
```

and add this code to your `MainApplication.java`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller;
import com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener;

@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    upgradeSecurityProvider();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

  private void upgradeSecurityProvider() {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, new ProviderInstallListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProviderInstalled() {

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderInstallFailed(int errorCode, Intent recoveryIntent) {
//        GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(errorCode, MainApplication.this);
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(MainApplication.this, errorCode);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please post your imports. Thx!

Comment: I've added the imports, welcome! @PhillipBrandonHolmes

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Very kind.

Comment: I would like to note one important detail: the device (or emulator) must have google play store installed, in order for the SSL layer to install properly. If it's an emulator, I recommend Genymotion and playstore from https://opengapps.org/.

Comment: How about the iOS part?

Comment: @PiotrBadura i don't know. i'm android expert.

Answer (score 1):

After numerous attempts to solve it, there is only one way that worked for me. Essentially you need to add a Java security package from Google to enable TLSv1/ TLSv1.1/ TLSv1.2 on old Android versions (< 5.0). This will also add support for TLSv1.3 as well as increase the apk size, but I guess we'll have to live with it.

Add the package in **app/build.gradle**:

```
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.1.0'
```

Update **MainApplication.java** to use the new security provider:

```
import java.security.Security;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider;
...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

Security.insertProviderAt(new org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider(), 1);

//...
}
```